# Can't connect controller to specific instance of Webots

Tags: python, webots

I am trying using Webots in combination with stable-baselines3 for reeinforcment-learning purpose.
I tried using Webot with multiple instances, but connecting the controller to a specific one doesn't work. It mostly connects to the newest one. I wrote a runtime.ini giving the WEBOT_PID manually looking like

```
[environment variables]
WEBOTS_PID=1492
```

and even tried setting the environment variable in my Python code like

```
os.environ["WEBOTS_PID"] = str(1492)
self.simulation = WebotsInterface()
```

it doesn't connect to desired Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WEBOTS_PID` environment variable should be set before you start the robot controller, otherwise it is not taken into account. So, you cannot set it in the `runtime.ini` (which is anyhow ignored when launching extern controllers) nor in the controller itself. I would recommend you to write a script that sets the `WEBOTS_PID` first and then starts the controller program as an extern controller.

Comment: Thank you, I do now know how it works since I went additionally through the source code. For my usecase a workaround using mutex to connect a threads controller to the newest instance was sufficient.